# I can not update when I use replication?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

In the Cloud SQL documentation, specifically on this link, "https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/features", mention the following:

unsupported statements for second generation instances

The following statements are not compatible because the second-generation instances use GTID replication:

statements CREATE TABLE ... SELECT
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE statements within transactions

Transactions or statements that update transactional and non-transactional tables

I often make updates to my data, so, that would be a problem for my solution.

In the google cloud documentation, in the same link mentioned above, it refers to the official documentation of mysql, which mentions that the restriction of updates are only with non-transactional engines.

Maybe I'm getting confused, but I really want to know if I can update my data or not. Sorry for the lousyness of English, it is obvious to say that I do not master it.

Answer (score 1):

The way I interpret this line: `Transactions or statements that update both transactional and nontransactional tables` is that transactions or statements that update BOTH transactional AND nontransactional tables at the same time, is not supported. *BOTH* being the key word.

I would like to think that you can still update transactional tables, and in a separately operation, update non-transactional tables.

Comment: What you tell me makes a lot of sense, but I have a bit of doubt, I will continue investigating.

Comment: Simon is correct. The statement refers to mixing updates to transactional and non-transactional tables. It wouldn't make a lot of sense to disallow all updates within transactions.